# Improper integral; don't know how to start!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am looking for tips to solve this integral. Problem is that I can´t figure out how to start.

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \exp(-x - \exp(-x)) = 1$$

Comment: Try putting $y=\exp(-x)$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $$e^{-x-e^{-x}}=e^{-x}e^{-e^{-x}}$$

Comment: So integration by parts? I didnt get nowhere with this.

Comment: @econ Call $u = e^{-x}$ and calculate ${\rm d}u$